# Work around for onclick event of option tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a multi-select drop-down on my web page and a checkbox to allow user to select all items in the list.

```
<select id="itemsList" multiple="true" size="3"></select>
<input type="checkbox" id="bSelectAll" onclick="selectAllItems();" />Select all
```

Clicking the checkbox selects all items in the list. Now when I click on one of the items in the list, that item remains selected while everything else is deselected. I want exact opposite behavior. When an item is clicked, that item should get deselected while everything else should remain selected.

I know we can get this behavior by ctrl+clicking on an item. However, requirement is that it should happen on normal click.

I tried to check onclick of an option tag but it seems that it is not according to standards and hence supported by only a subset of browsers.

I could not accomplish this by using onclick and onchange events of select tag.

The behavior should be consistent when checkbox is not checked. In short clicking on an option tag should always toggle its selection.

This would be the default behavior if I use a list of checkboxes instead of select box. However, is there any way of doing this with what I have as of now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using an array to keep record what been selected/deselected, and rebuild your options everytime user click.

js:

```
var record = [];

var selectAllItems = function (target) {
    //toggle all options here and keep a record in "record" array ...
}

var doTheMagic = function(target){
    record[target.selectedIndex] = ! record[target.selectedIndex];
    rebuildOptions();

}

var rebuildOptions = function (){
    var itemsList = document.getElementById('itemsList');
    for (var i=0;i<record.length;i++){
            itemsList.options[i].selected = record[i];
    }

}
```

html:

```
<select id="itemsList" multiple="true" size="3"  onclick="doTheMagic(this)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="bSelectAll" onclick="selectAllItems(this)" />Select all
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3A9Xs/3/

Comment: That's a good solution and thanks for looking into this! However, this is not working in IE(9). As I mentioned in the question, onclick of option tag does not work in all browsers, which is what you have used in your solution. Another minor problem can be - rebuilding of options shows some flickering in the dropdown. Perhaps we can live with that but it has to work on all browsers.

Comment: @Mandar I have updated the solution to listen to `onchange()` event on `<select>` instead. Hope it will work in IE(9). Yes, I noticed the flickering problem, it seems there is no way to prevent browser default behavior first, hopefully someone else would know a solution to that.

Comment: Again, thanks for spending time to update the solution! This works in IE now. However, changes you made have brought a side effect. I check select all checkbox and then go on deselecting items one by one until there is just one selected item left. Now there is no straight forward way to deselect that last item (unchecking the checkbox wouldn't work, for in our page, we uncheck it as soon as any one item is deselected) or to select another item instead of the last remaining item. If I decide to adopt your solution, I will have to fix that first.

Comment: @Mandar you're right. modified the solution again. Hope it works，

Comment: I ended up replacing the select box with a list of check boxes. But you were the first to answer with a work around I had sought originally. So marking it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet uses `onclick`, and should work for older IEs too.

In IEs `selectedIndex` always returns the first found selected index of the `select` instead of user selected index. A fix is to cache the current *value* of the `select`, which at the beginning of the function is the actually selected value. IE changes that value during the iteration, that's why caching is needed.

```
var select = document.getElementById('select'),
    toggle = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    options = select.options,
    selections = [],
    selectOption = function (e) {
        var n,
            target = e.target || e.srcElement,
            currentValue = target.value;
        for (n = 0; n < options.length; n++) {
            if (currentValue === options[n].value) { // or options[n].text, if values are not defined
                selections[n] = !selections[n];
            }
            options[n].selected = selections[n];
        }
    },
    toggleAll = function () {
        var n, bool = this.checked;
        for (n = 0; n < options.length; n++) {
            options[n].selected = bool;
            selections[n] = bool;
        }
    },
    n;
for (n = 0; n < options.length; n++) {
    selections.push(options[n].selected);
}
if (select.addEventListener) {
    select.addEventListener('click', selectOption);
    toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleAll);
} else {
    select.attachEvent('onclick', selectOption);
    toggle.attachEvent('onclick', toggleAll);
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKvTg/).

Comment: Taking a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up replacing the select box with a list of check boxes. Your answer was similar to what Ruocaled had suggested but I accepted his answer since he was the first one to respond with a good work around. Had SO allowed me to accept two answers I would have accepted yours as well. Thanks!