# onclick method of drop down menu not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Firstly Sorry if it is a duplicate question but I couldn't find the solution I was looking for.
Here is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
     <option> Select City </option>   
     <option onclick="document.getElementById('cityname').value='New York'">New York  </option>    
     <option onclick="document.getElementById('cityname').value='San Francisco'">San Francisco</option>     
     <option onclick="document.getElementById('cityname').value='Chicago'">Chicago  </option>   
      <option onclick="document.getElementById('cityname').value='Massachusetts'">Massachusetts        </option>   
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="cityname" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click on a cityname a popup appears.But This code is working in Firefox but not on chrome.I know I could use onchange() method but the problem is if user has selected say `New York` then first time the popup will appear but after closing popup if the user again clicks `New York` then the popup won't open.I want to open the popup on every click.

Comment: onClick for option is not allowed: see this for workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139701/work-around-for-onclick-event-of-option-tag

Comment: which popup are you talking about ? If the popup is getting open then what's the use of textbox here ?

Comment: @TusharRaj That input box is to just show that onclick not working in chrome.As far as popup is concernec sorry i can't show the code of popup

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<select name="level">
     <option value="">choose level</option>
     <option value="1">User</option>
     <option  value="2"> Mgr</option>
     <option  value="3">Hr</option>
</select>
```

U can get value by name of select(level).